# Drop Down List with option input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

There is any possibility to create drop down list with input textbox field we can create new list by textbox which is in same drop down list

Comment: What? Please reword your question, provide what you've tried, and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I want dropdownlist with having textbox input field in bottom of the list so i can insert new list from textbox

Comment: Again...still don't understand what you're trying to say...can you provide code examples you've tried? Because making a dropdown list is easy with the `<select>` element. The two places I'm confused are: "textbox input field in bottom of the list" and "insert new list from textbox"

Comment: wait for min...

Comment: Questions asking "Is there a way to do X?" / "Can I do X?" / "Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, the question is usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is you want. Right now, this is a "yes"/"no" question. Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way:

```js
$("#btnAdd").on('click', function(){
  var val = $('#txtItem').val().trim();
  if(!val) {
    alert('No value');
    return false;
  }
  $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {
      value: val,
      text: val
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect"></select>
<div>
  Item: <input type="text" id="txtItem"/>
  <button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <textarea id="listTxtArea" rows="4" cols="50">Type your input here...</textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="addToList()">Add to list</button>
  </div>
</div>
 
 
<script>
function addToList() {
$( "#listTxtArea" ).before( "<p>"+ $('#listTxtArea').val() +"</p>" );
$('#listTxtArea').val("Type your input here...");
}

</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Are you looking for something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/1etswz32/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [select2](https://select2.org/tagging) library with tagging option (also requires JQuery):

```js
$(".form-control").select2({
  tags: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option>purple</option>
</select>
```

You can open the drop down list, type in the textbox, and then press ENTER to add and select the new entry.